# Render thousands/millions times with React and Tauri (rust)

Tags: reactjs, rust, bigdata, tauri

I am learning Rust. I am creating a desktop app which read thousand/million rows of data in csv file and then transfer them one by one using tauri `event`.

Result: Rust has no problem read through the file (under 5 seconds). On the frontend side, my React app seems unable to keep up with events. On the screen, the `altitude` value is updated intermittently.

How to handle this situation is React? or What did I do wrong?

React side:

```
// App.js

import { listen } from '@tauri-apps/api/event';
import { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { invoke } from '@tauri-apps/api/tauri'

const App = () => {
  const [altitude, setAltitude] = useState("0");

  useEffect(() => {
    listen('rust-event', myCallback)
  }, [])

  const myCallback = useCallback((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    setAltitude(e.payload);
  },[])

  const handleClick = async () => {
    invoke('my_custom_command').catch(error => console.log(error));
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me To Start Fetching!</button>
        <span>{altitude}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Tauri side:

```
// main.rs
use arrow::csv;
use arrow::datatypes::{DataType, Field, Schema};
use std::fs::File;
use std::sync::Arc;
use arrow::array::{StringArray, ArrayRef};

#[tauri::command]
async fn my_custom_command(window: tauri::Window) {
  let schema = Schema::new(vec![
    Field::new("altitude", DataType::Utf8, false)
  ]);

  // Open file
  let file = File::open("src/data.csv").unwrap();

  // Get csv Reader using schema
  let mut csv = csv::Reader::new(file, Arc::new(schema), true, None, 1, None, None);

    // Loop through each row
    while let Some(m) = csv.next() {
      let n = m.unwrap();
      // Get reference of array of a column
      let col: &ArrayRef = n.column(0);
      // Cast the reference of array to array of string
      let col = col.as_any().downcast_ref::<StringArray>().unwrap();
      // Get value from the array using index
      let v = col.value(0);
      println!("{}", col.value(0));
      
      // Send each value through an event
      window
        .emit("rust-event", v)
        .expect("failed to emit");
    }
}

fn main() {
  tauri::Builder::default()
    .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![my_custom_command])
    .run(tauri::generate_context!())
    .expect("failed to run app");
}
```

Comment: Like people have already answered, Rust is super fast, javascript is super slow. Even just generating a couple thousand elements can be a challenge for javascript, let alone hundreds of thousands or millions. I recommend switching approach in your frontend. I recently made a simple life calendar that was meant to show one box per week in your life, but the frontend was way too laggy for that approach, so I switched to one box per year instead, and clicking a box brings up the weeks in that box. A similar solution might be preferable for you, simply due to limitations in your frontend.

Answer (score 1):

I personally do not suggest what you are doing as you can get a stack overflow.

The best would be to emit them in batch, you can fill a local buffer, when there are X elements (or the end is reached), emit the event, and clear the buffer.

#### Example

```rust
#[tauri::command]
async fn my_custom_command(window: tauri::Window) {
  // Your code
  // [...]

  // send 20 elements in the Vec (array)
  let should_trigger_at = 20;
  // local buffer
  let local_buffer: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

  // Loop through each row
  while let Some(m) = csv.next() {
    let n = m.unwrap();
    // Get reference of array of a column
    let col: &ArrayRef = n.column(0);
    // Cast the reference of array to array of string
    let col = col.as_any().downcast_ref::<StringArray>().unwrap();
    // Get value from the array using index
    let v = col.value(0);
    println!("{}", col.value(0));

    // add the value in the buffer
    local_buffer.push(col.value(0));

    if local_buffer.len() == should_trigger_at {
      // Send each value through an event
      window
        .emit("rust-event", local_buffer)
        .expect("failed to emit");

      // reset local buffer
      local_buffer = Vec::new();
    }
  }
  // if buffer not empty, lets emit the values
  if local_buffer.len() > 0 {
    window
      .emit("rust-event", local_buffer)
      .expect("failed to emit");
  }

  // [...]
  // Your code
}
```

*Please note*; doing this will send an `Array of String` to the Webview instead of a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess Rust is too fast :) React is unable to handle the speed.

I slow down the event emit with settimeout rust lib and I am happy with it for now.

```
// Before emit an event, delay it 100 microsecond;
set_timeout(Duration::from_micros(100)).await;

window
        .emit("rust-event", v)
        .expect("failed to emit");
```